# How to implement SAML based authentication in a native windows application in C#

Tags: c#, .net, saml-2.0

Am new to SAML. I just want to develop a simple prototype which used SAML authentication in a native windows application in C#. Any link or any code which helps me for this would be useful

Answer (score 0):

You need a client side SAML stack - refer [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html) .

But note that this is all via browser redirects so you need some kind of browser functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So is it not possible to implement SAML without using third party toolkit?

Comment: No - SAML is a complicated protocol with cryptographic requirements. You could do it but it would take a long time.